# Get the count of a specific action from a file by entering the last name only

Tags: php, count, get

So I have a .txt log that contains this:

```
2015-10-02 11:06:15: P          performed by 'Bruce Wayne' 
2015-1-23 11:06:15: P          performed by 'Bruce Wayne'
2015-11-06 9:06:15: S          performed by 'Peter Parker' 
2015-12-10 10:15:15: SAY          performed by 'Bruce Wayne' 
2015-9-10 10:06:15: SAY          performed by ' Wayne'
```

Some of them don't have a first name, instead they have a whitespace like shown above.

```
2015-9-10 10:06:15: SAY          performed by ' Wayne'
```

How can I get the count of all the commands done by a person by entering only the last name?

Example:
Input:
Wayne

Output:
P commands has been done by Wayne : 3 time(s)
SAY commands has been done by Wayne : 1 time(s)

Input:
Parker

Output:
S command has been done by Parker : 1 time(s)

I would appreciate some help for this. I have been trying to do it for over a week now.

Comment: what if text would contain a few men with the same lastname? e.g. `Bruce Wayne`, `Tom Wayne` - commands were made by different people

Comment: I wouldn't happen. It's all been filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`:

```
$surname = trim( $surname );

$pattern = "
    /
    ^                           # start of line
    (\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})     # date
    \s+                         # one-or-more spaces
    (\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):      # hour
    \s+                         # one-or-more spaces
    (\w+)                       # one-or-more word chars
    \s+                         # one-or-more spaces
    performed\sby\s             # “performed by ”
    '                           # single quote
    ((.*?\s)?{$surname})        # optional ( zero-or-more chars followed by a space ) followed by “$surname”
    '                           # single quote
    /xim
";

preg_match_all( $pattern, $text, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/RVXZI)**</kbd>

One-line pattern version:

```
/^(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):\s+(\w+)\s+performed\sby\s'((.*?\s)?{$surname})'/im
```